# Inserting values to pixels according to tuple

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

In the code below, I want to find all the pixels that are black after the threshold and convert them to green.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

# Two readings of the image - color and gray
color_img = cv2.imread('myimage.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

gray_img = cv2.imread('myimage.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Perform threshold
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_img, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Get indices of black pixels
indices = np.where(thresh == [0])

color = color_img.copy()

color[indices[0][:]][indices[1][:]][:] = [0, 255, 0]

cv2.imwrite('greens.jpg', color)
```

For some reason the pixels remain in the original value. Why do the values stay the same?

Comment: Do you have a test image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image and make greyscale version - don't annoy disks by reading twice!
color = cv2.imread('image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
gray  = cv2.cvtColor(color, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Perform threshold
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Set all pixels in "color" to green where threshold is zero
color[(thresh==0)] = [0, 255, 0]

# Save result
cv2.imwrite('greens.jpg', color)
```

So, if you start with this image:

[image]

You will get this as your result:

[image]